# Recording events triggered by the user over a specific time then re-playing them using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, event-listener

I created a page where the user will be shown specific images depending on the string (text) they type in a text input form. This all works perfectly.  The images are all hidden until the user selects them and they become visible for a few seconds then fade. The example of the code is below.

**HTML text input form**

```
<form>
   <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Type here">
    <button>Ok</button></div>
  </form>
```

**HTML hidden divs sample**

```
  <img id="story_018" class="hiddenElement" src="animsAll/Anims_018_We got a Story.gif">
              <img id="paris_006" class="hiddenElement" src="animsAll/Anims_006_paris.gif">
        <img id="sixties_014" class="hiddenElement" src="animsAll/Anims_014_sixties.gif">
```

**JQUERY/JS sample**

```
$( "input" )
      .keyup(function() {
        var value = $( this ).val();
        var sixties = "sixties";
        var paris = "paris";
        var weGotAStory = "story";
      if (value == sixties) {
        $("#button1960s_002").show().delay(10000).fadeOut();
      }   else if (value == paris) {
          $("#parisIsBurningButton_021").show().delay(10000).fadeOut();
        } else if (value == weGotAStory) {
            $("#wegotastory_019").show().delay(10000).fadeOut();
          }


      })
```

What I am trying to do now, is to **have the option of recording the user's selections as they pop up and have these selections be replayed to the user in the exact amount of time they were triggered.**

Of course each of the images has specific IDs that show, so the breakdown of actions is the following:

1. user clicks on buttons that starts and stop event listening  [*only this, I can do*]
2. record which IDs were made visible by the user [*not sure if it's possible or how*]
3. record the exact moment when these divs were triggered by the user [*not sure if it's possible or how*]
4. when the user clicks to end this event, take this information and replay it to the user.[ *if options 2 and 3 work, then this will be doable...*]

I have been looking for this and I have found the DOM mutation observers and time off functions but I am not sure how to connect the two, or if what I am attempting to do is even possible.

[background: I tried recording this literally using RecordRTC but it didn't work since these are not html-canvas-generated animations, and on top of that, even if I had converted the animations into html canvas and recorded them, the resulting video files would be massive. It makes no sense to create videos just for this.]

---

[update: I have been looking all over for some light into this, and I found an answer that gives me some direction. It's the last answer on this page  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42078213/6820506], and [a very helpful jsbin here](https://jsbin.com/nemake/edit?js) about recording and replaying javascript.

This is very complicated but since I am only listening for one type of show/hide event, it will be slightly easier. I would have to create a new iframe in order to basically re-write what the user did and then display that. I will work on it and come back with an answer once i manage to work around all the information]